# Asynchronous Multiple URL Pullers in iOS

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I was trying to solve this challenge for fun, http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2014/01/13/objective-c-coding-interview-challenge-urlpuller/, where it asks to asynchronously pull content for an array of urls. Now, I know how to pull content for one url using asynchronous methods of NSURLConnection using initWithRequest, Does this mean I have to create an array of NSURLConnections and requests to pull this off?

Answer (score 1):

yes. you have to create an array of NSURLConnection. But how about already-built network library like:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

http://allseeing-i.com/asihttprequest/ (Discontinued, but very powerful)

you can also use Cocoapods to import it. that's my favourite way